# android service stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

Hi currently I am implementing the notification function on android using alarm manager and service, however when I launch the application on an android device it show the error message that the app had stopped unexpectedly when I remove the app from the 'recent app' list by holding onto the home button. When the application is not remove from the 'recent app' list it works fine.

Can anyone advice what had I done wrong here?
Thanks for the response.

I have an activity which let user determine whether they want to receive notification or not. the value is then pass to the Trade.java

Trade.java

```
//the part where alarm manager is trigger
if(spApp_checkbox.getBoolean("checkbox", false) == true){
            if(spApp_checkbox.getInt("time", 0) <= 10){
                setTime = 60*1000;
            }
            else{
                setTime = spApp_checkbox.getInt("time", 0)*1000;
            }
            Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
              AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
              intent.setClass(this, MyService.class);

              PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
              alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.getTimeInMillis(), setTime, pendingIntent);
              this.startService(intent);
        }
        else{
            AlarmManager alarmManagerstop = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
              Intent intentstop = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
              PendingIntent senderstop = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intentstop, 0);
           // Cancel alarms
              try {
                  alarmManagerstop.cancel(senderstop);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.e("TAG", "AlarmManager update was not canceled. " + e.toString());
              }
              this.stopService(intentstop);
        }
```

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://pagecode/getTradeControlList_ByParameters";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://pagecode";
    private static String METHOD_NAME1 = "getTradeControlList_ByParameters";
    private static String URL = "";
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
           // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Destroy", 1).show();
           super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           // action to determine whether notification will be trigger
           Vector<SoapObject> obj1_new = showTrade(callby, tradeCrtl, days);
        int[] id_new = new int[obj1_new.size()];
        if(obj1_new != null){
            for (int i = 0; i < obj1_new.size(); i++) {
                    id_new[i] = Integer.valueOf(words[0]);

                    if(!hm.containsKey(id_new[i])){
                        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

                        PendingIntent in = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent_tr, 0);
                        System.out.println("list changes");
                        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Application")
                        .setContentText("New trade available")
                        .setProgress(0, 0, false)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
                        .setDeleteIntent(in)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

                    mBuilder.setContentIntent(in);
                    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
                    hm = new HashMap();
                    }           
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < obj1_new.size(); j++) {
                hm.put(id_new[j], id_new[j]);

            }
        }
           return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.android.app.AppSettings"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.android.app.Trade"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"></activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.android.app.MyService" 
            android:enabled="true"            
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please post your `log cat`

Comment: Can you please explain your problem better? How can you remove an application holding the home button? How can you remove an applcation from the recent apps? Are you killing the application process or just resuming it?

Comment: @chintankhetiya how can I see the log cat when running on a android device? Thanks

Comment: @type-a1pha When holding onto the home button, the list of recent app will appear, thereafter I swipe the app to the right it disappear from the list. Thanks

Comment: @jazebel: If you work with Eclipse or Android Studio, it's like when you use an AVD.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding START_STICKY as a return value in your Service's onstartCommand() method